# Which pattern is implemented by attached property in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns

In WPF, when we require extra behavior we generally implement attached property. Can any one tell which pattern its implemented?

Comment: [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) ?

Comment: [This blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bencon/2006/07/26/more-advanced-attached-property-use-the-ramora-pattern/) calls it the Ramora pattern, but as far as I can tell they made that name up. Do attached properties need to implement some specific named pattern?

Comment: Attached properties are more of a XAML concept and feature than a design pattern, but they can be though of as a variant of a visitor that defines a new "operation" to a class without changing it. Dependeny properties also implement the observer pattern.